# requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url

Tags: python, json, rest, python-requests

I am trying to create an object in a database using Python requests. I am able to do this with other URLs, but for this particular one I am getting errors. I am not sure if there is a problem with the actual request or the URL. Four items are required for creation, so I will just focus on those for now.

Below you will find an example of the request payload according to the documentation:

```py
def create_opportunity(self, data):
    try:
        r = requests.post(
            self.URL + 'sales/opportunities', data=data,
            headers=self.Header)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except:
        raise
    return r.json()

create_opp = '{"name": "My Opportunity", "primarySalesRep": {"name": "John Doe"}, "company": {"name": "My Company"}, "contact": {"name": "Jane Doe"}}'

opportunity = objCW.create_opportunity(create_opp)
```

payload example

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "primarySalesRep": {},
  "company": {},
  "contact": {}
}
```

primarsySalesRep

```
"primarySalesRep": {
    "id": 0,
    "identifier": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "_info": { }
},
```

company

```
"company": {
    "id": 0,
    "identifier": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "_info": { }
},
```

contact

```
"contact": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "_info": { }
},
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code `create_opp` is a string. [You shouldn't pass a string](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) in `data=` keyword of `post()` function of `requests`.

Given that server returns a JSON (`return r.json()`), I can guess that it receives JSON as well. Try to do something like this:

```py
def create_opportunity(self, data):
    r = requests.post(self.URL + 'sales/opportunities', json=data, headers=self.Header)
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.json()

create_opp = {
    "name": "My Opportunity", 
    "primarySalesRep": {"name": "John Doe"},  # maybe "id" or "identifier" is required? 
    "company": {"name": "My Company"},  # maybe "id" or "identifier" is required? 
    "contact": {"name": "Jane Doe"},
}

opportunity = objCW.create_opportunity(create_opp)
```